# C# nhibernate mulitier architecture

Tags: nhibernate, orm, repository

I need some advice: I would like do decouple nHibernate dependencies in the Presentation and Business Logic layers in order to have only the Data Access Logic layer referencing the nHibernate DLLs.

I only see solutions using SessionHelper/SessionManager objects and all being created used at the top layer. I beleave a better solution must exist.

What design pattern should I follow ? 
Can I wncapsulate the session (manager, helper, etc) in the repository pattern and easily change the ORM without forcing changes at the Business Logic layer ?

A code sample would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "easily change the ORM?" you could only use the least common denominator between all ORMS you might want to use. You will suffer from performance problems because you can't use a lot of features to enhance that and you will have leaky abstraction.

Comment: This question comes up a lot and the general answer is: don't do it.  There are very few cases where being able to swap out the ORM is worth the significant trade-offs required.  It's difficult to "hide" the ORM without completely neutering it.

Comment: Hi @MichaelMaddox: In theory I do not want to switch ORMs since the Client does not pay that kind of investment. My goal is to be able to implement base/generic classes (to apply in all my projects) and that allow me to hide what I do not want to be seen (i.e. dependencies to the ORM). I would like to encapsulate the nhibernate session, EF objectcontext, etc. How would you implement such a class ?

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a nice presentation about nHibernate Worst Practices](http://vimeo.com/16247125)

What you are asking is the first Worst Practice, so be sure to check it out

[You should check out the presenters nice blog which reviews these types of "architectures"](http://ayende.com/blog/153028/northwind-starter-kit-review-data-access-and-the-essence-of-needless-work-part-i)

"What design pattern should I follow"
Be sure to always use the common-sense design pattern and YAGNI :)